# Genericity on Relationship @EndNode

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a relation named "AUTHORED", this relation links a `User` and a `Tip` or a `Comment`, or a `Build`.

To avoid creating one class per relation endnode type, I decided to write a generic Authored class:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="AUTHORED")
public class Authored<T> {

    @GraphId Long id;

    @StartNode
    private User author;

    @EndNode
    private T entity;

    private Long date;

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public T getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public Long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Here is a part of my User class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends Entity{

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String ign;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private String email;

    @Relationship(type="AUTHORED", direction="OUTGOING")
    @JsonIgnore private Set<Authored<Tip>> tips = new HashSet<Authored<Tip>>();

    public Set<Tip> getTips() {
        Set<Tip> tips = new HashSet<Tip>();
        this.tips.forEach((t) -> {
            tips.add(t.getEntity());
        });
        return tips;
    }
...
...
```

Problem here is that I get a `RunTimeException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find a writer for the EndNode of relational entity com.bnstips.api.database.model.relation.Authored
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.createRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:340) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:280) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationships(GraphEntityMapper.java:243) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:143) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:117) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:81) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:48) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:82) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at com.bnstips.api.database.GenericService.find(GenericService.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.bnstips.api.endpoint.UserEndpoint.getUserTips(UserEndpoint.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
...........
...........
```

So, is it really possible to create Generic relationships? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: If this is not possible, Should I create one classe per Authored endnode type, or should I create 3 relationships, one per authored endnode type (`AUTHORED_TIP`, `AUTHORED_COMMENT` and `AUTHORED_BUILD`).

Comment: I think concrete relationships are the better modeling approach and the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic Authored isn't supported. Both your alternatives will work.

You can either have a specific relationship type per end node type, so three relationship entity classes annotated with different relationship types (`AUTHORED_TIP`, `AUTHORED_COMMENT` and `AUTHORED_BUILD`).

Or, use the same relationship type if that is what your model deems better. You still need three relationship entity classes, but annotated them with the same relationship type (`AUTHORED`). An example of this is the [Pizza](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/pizza/Pizza.java) class that has references to two relationship entities represented by the same relationship `HAS` -  [PizzaSeasoning](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/pizza/PizzaSeasoning.java) and [PizzaCheese](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/pizza/PizzaCheese.java)

Note that for both options above, your start/end node are specific and do not use generics.

Comment: At the moment I'm using inheritence to manage my relationship, and I filter the relation type using `entity.getClass()`. Since every model extends `Entity<T>` in my case, it works. But I think I'll create different relationships. If I create three relationships with just different `@EndNode`, will Neo4j fetch every `AUTHORED` relationship and then filter by `@EndNode`? Because if it does, I'll have to create three different relationship types, for performance.

Comment: In the current version of the OGM, all relationships attached to an entity are fetched in any case, so the performance would be the same. In a future version, the OGM will fetch only relationships exposed via your domain model so if you define only AUTHORED_COMMENT then only that relationship will be fetched. But if you define all three, then again, there is no performance boost since all 3 will be fetched. There isn't a plan yet to support fetching specific relationships only.